# Define Backbone view events when selectors are already jQuery objects?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, typescript

The typical way to setup events in a view is:

```
events: {
     'click .edit-button' : 'editThing',
     'click .delete-button' : 'destroyThing' 
},
```

If want to define all my DOM elements elsewhere for maintainability, e.g:

```
this.ui = {
    EDIT_BUTTONS : '.edit-button',
    DELETE_BUTTONS: '.delete-button',
}
```

Then I would just add this in like so:

```
 this.events = {};
 this.events["click " + this.ui.EDIT_BUTTONS] = "editThing";
 this.events["click " + this.ui.DELETE_BUTTONS] = "destroyThing";
```

Suppose I want to go one step further and instead of just defining all my dom selectors, I want to make them jQuery references:

```
this.ui = {
    EDIT_BUTTONS : this.$('.edit-button'),
    DELETE_BUTTONS: this.$('.delete-button'),
}
```

I want to do this because as the view grows in size, I want to avoid arbitrary jQuery dom lookups littered throughout my code, and can simply do something like:

```
this.ui.EDIT_BUTTONS.show() //or any other jQuery function.
```

My question is, if I have all my dom elements defined as jQuery objects, what would be a good way to add the initial click events, given that the standard syntax is string-based?

The reason for all of the above is I'm using TypeScript, and by adding a simple interface, anyone writing code can get intellisense code-completion for all available dom definitions.

Comment: I think you are missing the point here. You are using Backbone.js to segregate your model, view-model and templates. What purpose do you have in having your DOM elements declared elsewhere? If you follow good design, all the code that'll ever need to interact with a DOM element will be present in the same view in whose template the element is present. Can you give a practical scenario when you'd want to refer to DOM elements generated by one view to be used in another view?

Comment: Sorry, when I say elsewhere, I still mean in the same view. It's just that when the view starts to get large, there are very many casually placed selectors used for jQuery dom manipulation - adding / removing classes, scrolling, hiding, showing. What I want is to have all my selectors declared at the top.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. We have enforced this through code review till now. The only downside of your approach is high memory usage. None of the jquery objects will be garbage collected and all of them will be present since the beginning. If you are okay with that, we can figure out how to do what you want.

Comment: I hadn't thought about the garbage collection / memory aspect. I guess I'll have to just test it for performance and make a call. I'd read somewhere that it was good practice to predefine them to avoid repeating expensive dom queries. One potential solution to my problem is to use

    this.events["click" + this.ui.EDIT_BUTTONS.selector] = "editThing";

but I think the selector property is deprecated.

Comment: Yes. Anyways, why don't you use the delegateEvents() method of the view?

Comment: I don't see a big drawback in caching the jquery object references. The only case where I can see you'd want them garbage-collected would be if the view was no longer going to be used, in which case you'd want to remove the view anyway, which would subsequently remove the references you keep in the view.